# How to select the table heading of the first row in table using css selectors?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

table{
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.reference:nth-child(1) th:nth-child(1)    {background-color:green;}
table.reference tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color:red;}
table.reference tr:nth-child(even) {background-color:blue;}


}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<table class="reference">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris spécialités</td>
    <td>Marie Bertrand</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I want a different colour for my 1st row alone then followed by alternative colours for the following rows, but i dunno how to jus select my first row alone and give it a different colour. i can do it by giving different class names for each table row but i want to explore how to reduce the code complexity, can you please help me out?

Comment: like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/6zw5j40n/) add style for `th`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is just one row with `TH`s, use:

```
.reference th {background: green;}
```

If you want to style differently first row (doesn't matter if there are TH or TD), use `:first-child`

```
.reference tr:first-child {background: green;}
```

or

```
.reference tr:first-child th {background: green;}
```

Comment: Thank you pal.. :) that helped me alot and added over something new to to my store of knowledge.. :)